# Rear derailleur body rubs against chain when in highest gear

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear

I have a Vitus bicycle with a Claris groupset. When I put the bike in the highest gear, the chain starts to touch a part of rear derailleur.

I am still understanding how to fix my bike on my own. So don’t know what the specific part called.

I have tried aligning the gears and adjusting the high and low limiting screws, but nothing seems to create enough of a gap between the chain and rear derailleur when in highest gear.

[image: rubbing chains]

Comment: Have you ever changed the chain?  I suspect the current chain is too long for that gear combination.

Comment: Where is the chain at the front? Big ring or small ring?

Comment: the high and low limiting screws limit the sideways movement of the derailleur. They prevent the chain from going too far out. They do not limit the length. Your chain is too long, or the derailleur arm is too short. To decide which, we would need to see the derailleur position in the other extreme position.

Comment: Agree with Criggie, the chain is too long. Considering how small the biggest sprocket is I don’t think it’s a derailleur capacity problem. By the way: Wipe off the excessive lube from the chain, it only attracts dirt.

Comment: Just a side note: I assume this is small chainring, small cog. It’s better not to ride in this combo due to cross chaining. It creates more wear on the chain. It’s better to shift to the big ring. That said, an in-spec drivetrain with the correct chain length shouldn’t have the chain touch the RD cage in small-small.

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is a new situation with an existing chain, your chain is too long.

To fix this you need a chain breaker tool. You’ll use this many times over your bike riding life so buy a good quality one.

You appear to have a Shimano chain so you’ll need a Shimano compatible quick link to rejoin the chain.

Remove enough links so that the derailleur is barely tensioned in the small/small chain ring & cassette combo. Don’t remove so much that your derailleur is over tensioned in big/big. You can’t realistically add links back in so measure twice cut once.

Watch a video or two on how to use a chain breaker as it’s not 100% obvious for your first time.

Alternatively, your LBS should be able to do this very quickly and cheaply if you don’t want to invest in the tools yet.

Comment: "Remove enough links (link pairs) so that the derailleur is barely tensioned in the small/small chain ring & cassette combo." I think it’s more important to cut it so there is some small margin remaining in the big-big combination. This way you’ll get the best tension while staying on the safe side.

Comment: You can easily cut the chain next to the pin, remove the excess chain WITH the pin and close the chain with a quick link. There's even one available from Shimano. And there are enough videos on the Net about installing a chain at the correct length.

Comment: I hadn’t realised Shimano had come to the quick link party. That’s a much better plan than the pin.

Comment: I refrained from commenting about quick links because I wasn't sure if one came stock with Claris chains. It may not matter, the OP could get one from any reputable third party, e.g. KMC, Wipperman, even SRAM. And yes, I am going to guess that quick links will be easier for most cyclists to join reliably than the chain pins.